# Chart.js - how do you show a different image for each point on a scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am getting an array of 8 players, each with a player image which is the file destination for each player's image. I can display one direct image for every point if defining yourImage directly to a file destination and adding it as a pointStyle in the datasets.

Questions is how do you add each player_image for each point? I can get each file destination individually in the players.forEach function but I'm not sure how to link it to the chart

```
 // Extract the necessary data from the players array
  var data = players.map(function(player) {
    return {
      x: player.age,
      y: player.avg_ranking,
        player_id: player.player_id,
        player_name: player.player_name,
        player_image: player.image
    };
  });

  players.forEach(function(player){
        console.log(player.image);
        var yourImage = new Image();
        yourImage.src = player.image;
  })


  // Create a new Chart.js chart
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Average Ranking by Age',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 10,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
      }]
    },
```

I tried putting directly an image filename into MyImage and that correctly displayed the same image for each. It'ss the array with all the file destinations

It might be dumb but I was able to display each image like this:

```
  var playername0 = data[0].player_name;
   var playername1 = data[1].player_name;
   var playername2 = data[2].player_name;
   var playername3 = data[3].player_name;
   var playername4 = data[4].player_name;
   var playername5 = data[5].player_name;
   var playername6 = data[6].player_name;
   var playername7 = data[7].player_name;


   var yourImage1 = new Image()
  yourImage1.src = data[1].player_image;
   var yourImage2 = new Image()
  yourImage2.src = data[2].player_image;
   var yourImage3 = new Image()
  yourImage3.src = data[3].player_image;
   var yourImage4 = new Image()
  yourImage4.src = data[4].player_image;
   var yourImage5 = new Image()
  yourImage5.src = data[5].player_image;
   var yourImage6 = new Image()
  yourImage6.src = data[6].player_image;
   var yourImage7 = new Image()
  yourImage7.src = data[7].player_image;


  var imageData = {
    labels: [playername0, playername1, playername2, playername3,playername4, playername5, playername6, playername7],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Average Ranking by Age',
      pointRadius: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      pointHoverRadius: 20,
      pointHitRadius: 20,
      pointStyle: [yourImage0, yourImage1, yourImage2, yourImage3,yourImage4, yourImage5, yourImage6, yourImage7],
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,191,255)",
      data: data
    }]
  }

// Create a new Chart.js chart
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: imageData,
```

Comment: It's not dumb, it works like that, afaik.